# Character alignment weird output

Tags: c

My code is at the bottom.  I'm trying to take two strings and change them as per the edit transcript that I receive.  I wrote my code but I don't understand why I'm getting such a weird output.  My goal is to first store the values of the two strings then make them into a 2D array afterwards, but I'm failing on part one of that goal.  Here's the problem:

Create a function that meets the following:

Input: an edit transcript, and 2 original strings (3 strings)

Output: a 2 d array containing the two alignments post edit

Example:

```
s1 = “vintner”
s2 = “writers”
trans = “RIMDMDMMI”
```

R stands for "replace"
I stands for "insert"
M stands for "match"
D stands for "delete"
Answer:

```
alignment={“v_intner_”,
“wri_t_ers”}; //return a 2d array
```

Function prototype:

```
char** getAlignment(char* s1, char* s2, char* s3);
```

Here's my code below:

```
char TestS1[] = "vintner";
char TestS2[] = "writers";
char TestS3[] = "RIMDMDMMI";
char twoDarray[2][10];

char** getAlignment(char* s1, char* s2, char* s3){
    char transTemp[n];
    char s1Temp[n];
    char s2Temp[n];
    char sOne[n];
    char sTwo[n];
    strcpy(sOne, s1);
    strcpy(sTwo, s2);
    int jj;
    strcpy(transTemp, s3);
    int kk;
    for(jj=0, kk=0; jj<n, kk<n; jj++, kk++){

        if(transTemp[jj]=='R')
        {
            s1Temp[kk] = sOne[jj];
            s2Temp[kk] = sTwo[jj];
        }

        if(transTemp[jj]=='I'){
            s1Temp[kk] = '_';
            s1Temp[kk+1] = sOne[jj];
            s2Temp[kk] = sTwo[jj];
            kk++;
        }

        if(transTemp[jj] == 'M'){
            s1Temp[kk] = sOne[jj];
            s2Temp[kk] = sTwo[jj];
        }

        if(transTemp[jj] == 'D'){
            s2Temp[kk] = '_';
            s2Temp[kk+1] = sTwo[jj];
            s1Temp[kk] = sOne[jj];
            kk++;
        }


    }

    printf("\ns1Temp = %s\n", s1Temp);
    printf("\ns2Temp = %s\n", s2Temp);


    return 0;
}

main()
{
printf("The new method returns: ", getAlignment(TestS1,TestS2,TestS3));
return 0;
}
```

Comment: No format specifier here:`printf("The new method returns: ", getAlignment(TestS1,TestS2,TestS3));`

Comment: Yea, thanks for pointing that out.  However, I didn't really care about what happened with that printf statement.  I just wanted to call the function.  The values that I'm focused on are printed out in the function.

Comment: You are trying to return an `int` with a function designed to return a `char**`

Comment: So I should return a 2d array correct?  Because that didn't work.

Comment: Since `twoDarray` is global,there is no need to return it. Change the return type of the function to `void`.

Comment: I did that and I still get a weird output.  The two strings are different from what I expect.  have you tried to run the code?

Comment: What is `n` in your code?

Comment: n is 10.  I got it to work better by changing a few lines in the for loop.  This is the new and improved for loop.  My answer is almost perfectly what I want it to be but I'm trying to figure out what's causing this new difference.

Comment: if(transTemp[jj]=='I'){
                s1Temp[kk] = '_';
                s1Temp[kk+1] = sOne[jj];
                s2Temp[kk] = sTwo[jj];
                s2Temp[kk+1] = sTwo[jj+1];
                kk++;
            }

Comment: Your loop condition `jj<n, kk<n` has a comma and probably doesn't do what you want; the first sub-condition is evaluated, but not used. You'll probably want `jj<n && kk<n` here.

Comment: @CoolGuy: `0` is a valid representation of the null pointer. (In fact, it is the only one recognised by the core language, `NULL` is a symbol defined in `<stdlib.h>`.)

Answer (score 1):

Your question really has two parts: How can I return two strings? And why don't I get the desired output?

Strings in C are character arrays. You seldom return strings. It is more common to pass a character array to a function, together with its maximum length, and fill that array. The functions in `<string.h>` do that. A good design model is, in my opinion, `snprintf`: It fills the buffer, takes care not to overflow it, ensures that the result is properly null-terminated and returns the number of characters written had the buffer been big enough. That last property allows you to pass a length of null (and as a special case the `NULL` pointer) to find out how many chars you need and allocate memory as appropriate.

So the prototype for your function could look like this:

```
int getAlignment(char *res1, char *res2, size_t n,
    const char* s1, const char* s2, const char* trans);
```

Except that the resulting strings could be of different length in your case.

You can also return strings, but you'll either have to return new memory allocated with `malloc` on the heap, which means the client code must  explicitly `free` it, or pointers into already existing memory. You can, of course, only return one string.

You can return multiple values from a function as a struct. Structs do not decay into pointers when passing them to or returning them from functions. I'll use that approach in my example below.

As for the second question: Your main problem is that you have three strings - two source strings and one translation string - but keep only two indices. All strings are traversed independently; there is no synchronisation between the strings' indices.

You append to the result strings as you go. The "driving" string is the trenslation string, so you should traverse only that with the main loop.

Another thing to note is that you don't need to make copies of the source strings. This is not only inneccessary, it is also dangerous, because `strcpy` could overflow the buffers. Taking care of overflow with `strncpy` couldtruncate the input strings.

I've updated your implementation:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define N 10

struct Result {
    char res1[N];
    char res2[N];
};

struct Result getAlignment(const char* s1, const char* s2, const char* trans)
{
    struct Result res;

    int j1 = 0;             // index into s1
    int j2 = 0;             // index into s2
    int n = N - 1;          // leave 1 char for null terminator

    while (*trans) {

        if (*trans == 'R') {
            if (j1 < n) res.res1[j1++] = *s1++;
            if (j2 < n) res.res2[j2++] = *s2++;
        }

        if (*trans == 'I'){
            if (j1 < n) res.res1[j1++] = '_';
            if (j1 < n) res.res1[j1++] = *s1++;
            if (j2 < n) res.res2[j2++] = *s2++;
        }

        if (*trans == 'M') {
            if (j1 < n) res.res1[j1++] = *s1++;
            if (j2 < n) res.res2[j2++] = *s2++;
        }

        if (*trans == 'D') {
            if (j1 < n) res.res1[j1++] = *s1++;
            if (j2 < n) res.res2[j2++] = '_';
            if (j2 < n) res.res2[j2++] = *s2++;
        }

        trans++;
    }

    // null-terminate strings
    res.res1[j1] = '\0';
    res.res2[j2] = '\0';

    return res;
}

int main()
{
    char *str1 = "vintner";
    char *str2 = "writers";
    char *trans = "RIMDMDMMI";

    struct Result res = getAlignment(str1, str2, trans);

    printf("%s\n%s\n\n", res.res1, res.res2);

    return 0;
}
```

Things to note:

- The translation string is traversed via pointer, which saves an index.
- The result strings are appended to only if there is enough space. You can change `N` to 5 and see how the result strings are truncated after 4 characters, thus losing information, but preventing buffer overflows.
- Both result-string indices and source string pointers are incrementes as you go.
- The source strings are only read from. (That's why copying doesn't make sense.) So they should be `const char *` in the function signature.